# Task running even after killing it

Tags: linux, process

I am running kibana service in centos using nginx. [kibana deployment](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-) - i followed this .

When I check Kibana status i am getting as not running,

[image]

But when i see it using `ps -eaf | grep kibana`  i am getting the below PID and running status,

```
kibana   20185     1  0 04:28 ?        00:00:03 /opt/kibana/bin/../node/bin/node /opt/kibana/bin/../src/cli
```

I tried to kill the process using `kill 20185` but it is taking some new PID and running again.

How to kill the task running (ie, running automatically even after kill pid comment)

Comment: don't post a screenshot when text will do.  copy and paste the text from your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

`systemd` probably "lost control" over the service somehow. This can happen if, for example, the example, the executable's path changes. However, if the process is respawning even after being killed, then either:

1. `systemd` is still controlling the program by (another) auto restarting service.
2. Some other daemon is playing `systemd`'s game and respawning the process.

If we look at your `ps -eaf` output...

```
kibana   20185     1  0 04:28 ?        00:00:03 /opt/kibana/bin/../node/bin/node /opt/kibana/bin/../src/cli
```

This gives us some important details:

- The process' ID is `20185`.
- The process' parent's ID is `1`.

As the PPID is `1`, we can safely assume that `systemd` is the responsible one here. So, this command should tell you what unit is controlling the process...

```
$ systemctl status 20185
```

From there on, you can make your way to stop/kill the program.